# Divs with background images, Height set according to screen size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am building a responsive site. So am having a bit of a battle with different screen sizes.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3s' Grid System for this, So everything is percentage based.

I for example have a box called "feature1". I have set that to 400px, Which works fine say on a smaller screen. However on a larger screen, I would like that to match somewhere close to the screens' height.

Has anyone achieved this before?

I am willing to look at jQuery alternatives to set a height based on screen height.

My CSS at the moment is as follows :

```
.feature1 {
background: red;
height: 400px;
}

.feature2 {
background: green;
height: 400px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use CSS Media queries would allow you to set discrete widths

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .feature2 {
    height: whatever;
  }
}
```

In JQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  windWidth = $(window).width();
  $(".feature2").height(windWidth*.3);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Sridhar R interesting that you have used jQuery there, Can you explain the maths on the windWidth? 

Thanks

Comment: windWidth is give current window width based on that you will set your div height

Comment: Thanks! I've done that divided by 2 and the boxes are seeming to fit pretty much how I'd like! Much appreciated

Comment: i created example fiddle check http://jsfiddle.net/aq3uE/ if it helps accept as answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use `background-size: 100%;` but keep in mind that it's not implemented on all browsers yet

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed widths, you will run into problems with different screen sizes. You should be using min/max widths and using media queries to detect the screen size and throw out the CSS based on the screen size.

See here for further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I am using Bootstrap 3 (Will ammend question to say that) So the cols' are percentage based.

Answer (score 1):

you can use min-height with media queries , you target similar various screens. as coming to 
  backgrounds-size -> you use **100%** or **'cover'** for wide screens

```
      @media (min-height: 400px) and (max-height: 600px) {
     .feature2 {
    height: whatever;
   }
  }
```